# How to get a number from the Call log and use it to save to an Object - Android

Tags: java, android

From the android device i do need to select a number from the CAll Log and use it to set in my own object . I am looking at CallLog.Calls but only outgoing is provided?

Answer (score 3):

I use the following to query the Call Log.

```
    final String[] projection = null;
    final String selection = null;
    final String[] selectionArgs = null;
    final String sortOrder = "DATE DESC";
    Cursor cursor = _context.getContentResolver().query(
            Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls"),
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            sortOrder);
    if (cursor != null) {
        //Loop through the call log.
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) { 
            //Common Call Log Items
            String callNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
            String callDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE));
            String callType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE));
            String isCallNew = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NEW));
            //DO YOUR WORK HERE...
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. This solution is working for all call logs. But what intent are you using? The actual problem is getting the contentUri of "selected" contact. How to make user select a call log.

Comment: This sounds like a new question. You should search or create a new question with your specific scenario.

Comment: I have. Turns out there is no Intent to do that, unlike picking contacts. Thanks for your response.